# RegEx in php - need to remove [sometext ... ] from variable

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I need a simple help:
need to match:

```
[sometext]
[sometext value=1]
[sometext value=1 anothervalue=2]
```

with php regex and replace with null in entire $content variable

```
$content = str_replace('/??????/','',$content);
```

What should I place instead of question marks?

Ps... anybody know a good resource for dummies to learn regex?

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove, `sometext` or `[sometext value=1 anothervalue=2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex that you should use should be something like:

```
/\[[^\]]*\]/
```

It basically breaks down to:

- `\[` matches the opening square bracket.
- `[^\]]*` matches anything until the next closing square bracket.
- `\]` matches the ending square bracket.

Also, you should use `preg_replace`, as `str_replace` doesn't accept a regex. So you end up with:

```
$content = preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', '', $content);
```

You can find plenty of info about the regex flavour used in PHP in the [PCRE regex syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) page of the PHP doc.

Comment: Ok, as it is WordPress problem and it sadly goes a little deeper, I need to each representation of:

    <div class="sometestclass">
       <img ....>
       <div>.....</div>
       any other html tags
    </div><!-- END: .sometestclass -->

The only idea I have is to match everything that starts with:
   
    <div class="sometestclass">

And ends with:

    <!-- END: .sometestclass -->

with all that is between.
Anybody have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Of course I need to remove this "parent div" which has known beginning and is specially taged at end, and with all inside.

Comment: So, basically, you want to remove all the `div` elements with some specific class, as well as all their content, right? In that case, I think you should consider a different approach, like using PHP DOM to build a DOM tree with your HTML and then doing the necessary DOM removal operations. A regex to do that will be way to complicated.